# Parallel for "for loops"

Tags: for-loop, parallel-processing

I am trying for the first time to parallelize a for loop in python.

This is my original for loop:

```py
for i in sequences:
  wchk_matrix(i, 2, wchk)
```

The function should iterate over a sequence and update the matrix "wchk".
The thing is that i have 1000 sequences, so it gets slow a bit. 
That's why i would like to parallelize it, does anyone have any idea, how to do it?

I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```py
with mp.Pool(4) as pool:
  pool.map(wchk_matrix, [wchk_matrix(i, 2, wchk) for i in sequences])
```

Would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

From [multiprocessing library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map):

> - `map(func, iterable[, chunksize])`
>
>   A parallel equivalent of the `map()` built-in function (**it supports only one iterable argument though, for multiple iterables see `starmap()`**).
> - `starmap(func, iterable[, chunksize])`
>
>   Like `map()` except that the elements of the iterable are expected to be iterables that are unpacked as arguments.
>
>   Hence an iterable of `[(1,2), (3, 4)]` results in `[func(1,2), func(3,4)]`.
>
>   *New in version 3.3.*

`wchk_matrix` expects three arguments, so you need to create a list of tuples with three values:

```py
with mp.Pool(4) as pool:
  pool.starmap(wchk_matrix, [(i, 2, wchk) for i in sequences])
```

But note that any in-place modification to `wchk` will be ignored, once the data is copied multiple times to fill the list, and copied each time the interpreter creates a fork for Pool. The best to do is calculate a value and return, so gather all the results in a list that `starmap` actually returns.